# Trial account redirect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

I'm working on a rails application and I would like to include a function that would allow a user to have a 3 day free trial, without a credit card.  I was thinking I should just create a redirect when they take an action, in this case, creating a new document using this code intially:

```
  def new
    if current_user.created_at <= 3.days.ago
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    else
      @document = Document.new
      @document.user_id = current_user.id
    end
  end
```

This worked just fine for any accounts older than 3 days.

However, I also need to check against whether or not the user is already subscribed, or any user with a account length longer than 3 days will be redirected through the same loop.  Each of my users have a `subscribed` boolean field associated with them, which is changed to `true` when the stripe API is executed.

Here's my second attempt, which still results in the loop:

```
  def new
      if current_user.created_at <= 3.minutes.ago
        redirect_to new_charge_path
      else
        @document = Document.new
        @document.user_id = current_user.id
      unless current_user.subscribed = 'true'
      end
      end
  end
```

I think I'm using `if` `else` and `unless` incorrectly in this case, but I'm new so I'm not sure where to start to get the functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to flip it to

```
current_user.created_at >= 3.minutes.ago
```

Also if this is something you want on every action you should write a method in your `application_controller` and call that method as a `before_action`

Something like this in your application controller:

```
def check_subscription
    if current_user.created_at <= 3.days.ago && !current_user.subscribed
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end
end
```

and then you can call `before_action :check_subscription`

Comment: Worked, thank you.  I only wanted this on the create action so I chose not to include the `before_action` but glad you provided that for informational purposes.

Comment: @PSCampbell if you wanted to clean up your controller a bit you could do `before_action :check_subscription, only: [:create]`